# Default of Drop down also applying to RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two fields a drop down for years and a textbox to enter a VIN number. I have the regEx working exactly how I want it but the problem I am having is if a year is not chosen it still validates because the VIN is waiting on the year. How can I enter either date not existing yet or the "Select Year" to also apply with the RegEx?

When I do console.log(date) it returns 0 and the validation is hitting the second regEx because it is 0 which is less than 1981.

Somehow I have to write less than 1981 but greater than 0 I have tried so many different combinations and just seem to not be able to find the correct answer.

```
var date = Number($("#vehicleyear").val());
  var re;
  if (date >= 1981) {
    re = new RegExp("^[A-HJ-NPR-Za-hj-npr-z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Za-hj-npr-z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$");
  } else if (date < 1981) {
    re = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z\\d]{2,17}$");
  } else {}
  return vin.match(re);
}, 'Please enter valid VIN.');
```

I tried applying the regEx in the else statement and that did not work either. (Saying if its anything else but that still apply the RegEx)

**HTML**

```
<label for="vehicleyear">Year:</label>
  <select name="vehicleyear" id="vehicleyear" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Year</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <!-- And so on -->
  </select>
```

Comment: why not just check to see if a year has been selected before validating the VIN? Also, what is the point of a blank `else {}`?

Comment: What does the HTML look like for your form? Also, that doesn't look like it's the full function above

Comment: Right, so what does the HTML look like for your drop down menu? there has to be a value for each of the menu options. What is the default Null value?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(date)` to see how it looks like. I assume you have debug tools installed and a console opened, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, an empty string transformed to a number is 0, so what you want to do is always fail if the value is zero, so in other words, something like this:

```
if(date <= 0)
{
    return false;
}
// other if() after
var re;
if (date >= 1981)
{
...
```

Comment: The else part of the 2nd if() would be when the date is less than 1981. But I thought your main problem was the case when no date was selected...